# Создать файловую карту диска - показать файл с какого и по какой сектор занимает

Tags: delphi, disk

Собственно надо слева список файлов, справа номера секторов которые он занимает. С MFT общался, но не настолько. Проблема получить список секторов относящихся к файлу. UnErase в NTFS примерно понял.